# How to self register a service with Consul

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, consul

I'm trying to [self](http://microservices.io/patterns/self-registration.html) register my ASP.NET Core application to Consul registry on startup and deregister it on shutdown.

From [here](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/agent.html#agent_service_register) I can gather that calling the http api [`put /v1/agent/service/register`] might be the way to go (or maybe not!).

From my app, I thought I'll target the `Startup` class, starting with adding the my `.json` file

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   var builder = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("consulconfig.json");
   Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

But now, I'm stuck as `ConfigureServices` method tells me thats where I add services to the container, and `Configure` method is where I configure the Http request pipeline.

Anybody to point me in the right directions, online readings, examples, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all I recommend to use [Consul.NET](https://github.com/PlayFab/consuldotnet)
 to interact with Consul. Using it, a service registration may look like:

```
var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration
{
    Name = "foo",
    Port = 4242,
    Address = "http://bar"
};

using (var client = new ConsulClient())
{
    await client.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration);
}
```

Now let's integrate this code into ASP.NET Core startup process with help of DI and loose coupling. Read your json file into `ConsulOptions` instance (DTO without any logic):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<ConsulOptions>(Configuration);
}
```

Encapsulate all Consul-related logic in class `ConsulService` accepting `ConsulOptions` as a dependency:

```
public class ConsulService : IDisposable
{
    public ConsulService(IOptions<ConsulOptions> optAccessor) { }

    public void Register() 
    {
        //possible implementation of synchronous API
        client.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Add the class itself to the DI container:

```
services.AddTransient<ConsulService>();
```

Then create an extention method of `IApplicationBuilder` and call it:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.ConsulRegister();
}
```

In `ConsulRegister` implementation we add our hooks on application start/stop:

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ConsulService Service { get; set; }

    public static IApplicationBuilder ConsulRegister(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //design ConsulService class as long-lived or store ApplicationServices instead
        Service = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ConsulService>();

        var life = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();

        life.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        life.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);

        return app;
    }

    private static void OnStarted()
    {
        Service.Register(); //finally, register the API in Consul
    }
}
```

Locking absence and static fields are OK because the `Startup` class is executed exactly once on application start. Don't forget to de-register the API in `OnStopping` method!

Comment: will `OnStarted` called once or with every request? I haven't got a full grasp of `Configure` method and `middlewares`

Comment: also wouldn't `ConsulService.Register` be `async Task Register` as I'll `await client.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration)`?

Comment: @rm, `OnStarted` is called once. Yes, `ServiceRegister` is async by default, you can easily make it syncronous with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: how will I use it asynchronously? I tried `life.ApplicationStarted.Register(async () => OnStarted)` which didn't work.

Comment: @rm, I've changed `ConsulService` implementation to show how to call async Consul.NET methods from synchronous code.

Comment: @Ilya Chumakov

Service registration works fine for me. I am able to register services with node with similar code as above. However, my expectation was when registering the service with one node it should be registered or replicated to all the other nodes in the data center. While in my case the service is shown only under one node. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You can use tools like Registrar(http://gliderlabs.github.io/registrator/latest/) for auto registration of your services.

Comment: Where does the damn 'client' come from? A virtual, selfgenerated, imaginary and abstract varible, my IDE does not like?
Please explain.

Comment: @Banzai `var client = new ConsulClient()`. The first example from Consul.NET readme.

Comment: OK, seems I dont ask clearly enough, sorry, my fault:
In 'public class ConsulService : IDisposable' the 'client' is used without any reference. Should here added using(client = ...){} around the client.Agent... thing?
It be a fine thing, to find a complete example with register/deregister a service with Consul.NET anywhere on the internet.

Comment: @Banzai, the client lifetime is up to you. Yes, the simplest solution is to add `using(var client = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

> Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddConsulConfig(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseConsul();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

> AppExtensions.cs

```
using Consul;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class AppExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddConsulConfig(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConsulClient, ConsulClient>(p => new ConsulClient(consulConfig =>
            {
                var address = configuration.GetValue<string>("http://localhost:8500");
                consulConfig.Address = new Uri(address);
            }));
            return services;
        }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseConsul(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            var consulClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IConsulClient>();
            var logger = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("AppExtensions");
            var lifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>();


            // var uri = new Uri(address);
            // Better approach should be used to set the below settings. I hard coded just to explain.
            var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration()
            {
                ID = $"MyService",
                Name = "WebApplication1",
                Address = "localhost", //$"{uri.Host}",
                Port = 57084  // uri.Port
            };

            logger.LogInformation("Registering with Consul");
            consulClient.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID).ConfigureAwait(true);
            consulClient.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration).ConfigureAwait(true);

            lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Unregistering from Consul");
                consulClient.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID).ConfigureAwait(true);
            });

            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/narottamgoyal/api.gateway.with.service.discovery/tree/master/WebApplication1)